# syntax to bind non-observable property of a viewmodel observable property in knockout.js

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-2.0

I have a view model as below :

```
function foo(param){

    this.prop = param;

};

var viewModel = function(){

    this.foo = ko.observable();

};
```

and in the view

```
<input type="text" data-bind="value: foo.prop" />
```

in the view , when I use the syntax

```
<span data-bind="text: foo.prop" ></span>
```

it shows nothing and has no reaction to updates but with

```
<div data-bind="with: foo" >
    <span data-bind="text: prop" ></span>
</div>
```

it works and changes when value changes .

what's wrong with first implementation ?

Answer (score 1):

In your ViewModel if you are using some variable which is another object i think you better in this object definition mark it's variables as observable..
for example you can do something like this:

```
function FooClass(param) {
    this.prop = ko.observable(param);
};

function viewModel() {
    this.foo = new FooClass('Hello World');
};
ko.applyBindings(new viewModel());
```

[jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/hSm7J/)

Comment: thankyou for your answer . I just added a default value to the property ( this.foo = ko.observable("") ) and it starts working !